# What is a sub-registrar?

Tags: registrars

I was looking at the [standardized contracts page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Standardized_Contract_APIs) and was confused by the description for `setSubRegistrar` and `subRegistrar`.

Here's the description for `setSubRegistrar`: Records the name as referring to a sub-registrar at the given address.

I understand what a registrar is but am confused by the idea of a sub-registrar and was hoping someone could give a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It allows for the creation of hierarchical name registrations.

Instead of just allowing you to register, for example, "`foo`" as being associated with one address, and "`bar`" with another, it would allow you to create a tiered name system, allowing for things like "`foo/bar`". (I think the idea was to make it more like DNS.)